# Array.find() vs binary search vs Array.forEach() in sorted array

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering , which method should be faster.
I know that if array not sorted native find or forEach would be better suit for it, but if array is sorted already?
For example i got sorted array `[{a: 1},{a:2},{a:3}...]` and i need find some an element where a = x
which method is better, Array.find(), binary search or Array.forEach()?

Comment: `.find`/`.forEach` are both `O(n)`, while a binary search is `O(log n)`. How that correlates with running time is a different matter, especially since it also depends on the environment and the data

Comment: If the array is sorted then definitely binary search has the least time complexity, so it the better choice of the three.